# RequireJS does not load dependencies consistently

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I was tasked to implement requireJS architecture in an existing project. The project is a single page app, though it has another page for order form. After some documentation lurking and experimentation I was able to get the ball rolling.

But my happines soon faded, as I realised it does not work as expected. When page is reloaded sometimes it works and other times throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $beforeafter.beforeAfter is not a function

I wrote my config file (also 'data-main' entry point in html script tag) as follows:

**config.js:**

```
// RequireJS configuration, see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config
require.config({
  // TODO: set the right path and clean up all the '../../' nonsense
  baseUrl: '',
  paths: {
    // Vendor JavaScript
    jquery: "../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
    jqueryui: "../../src/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui",
    bootstrap: "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
    jquerycookie: "../../node_modules/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie",
    owlcarousel: "../../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel",
    jquerybrowser: "../../node_modules/jquery.browser/dist/jquery.browser",
    beforeafter: "../../src/vendor/before-after/jquery.beforeafter-1.4",
    upload: "../../src/vendor/requirejs-upload/upload",
    touchpunch: "../../src/vendor/touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch",
    // Our custom modules
    main: "../../src/js/modules/main",
    gallery: "../../src/js/modules/gallery",
    form: "../../src/js/modules/form"
  },
  shim: {
    "jqueryui": {
      exports: "ui",
      deps: ["jquery"]
     },
    "bootstrap": {
      deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "owlcarousel": {
      deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "beforeafter": {
      deps: ["jquery", "jqueryui"]
    },
    "touchpunch": {
      deps: ["jquery", "jqueryui"]
    }
  }
});

// Start the application
require(['main']);
```

I think this error has something to do with AMD non-compatible scripts (beforeAfter) and shim settings, but it could as easily have something to do with the way I used `require()` and `define()` therefore I'm including the rest of the structure:

**modules/main.js:**

```
define(['jquery', 'jquerycookie', 'bootstrap', 'touchpunch', 'gallery', 
'form', 'owlcarousel'],
function ($, jquerycookie, bootstrap, touchpunch, gallery, form, owlcarousel) {

  var menuItems = undefined;
  // + a lot of other variables

  function setUsersDeviceWidth() {
    // some code and a lot of other functions after this one
  }

  function resizeCarousel() {
    // this is where I use my custom module (gallery.js) and this works normally
    gallery.resizeCarousel($this);
  }

  // This file also holds and executes jQuery .ready function
  $(document).ready(function(){
     // I use my model again, it's working
     gallery.initializeCarousel();
     // + a lot of other code
  });
});
```

And module that throws the error:

**modules/gallery.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'touchpunch', 'owlcarousel', 'beforeafter'],
function ($, touchpunch, owlcarousel, beforeafter) { 

  var carousel = $('#carousel');

  // function for initialisation in main.js, part of return object
  var initializeCarousel = function() {
     // 'owlcarousel' modules 'owlCarousel()' function works like it should
     carousel.owlCarousel(options);
     // it also initialises beforeAfter, where the problem occurs
     initializeBeforeAfter($item);
  });

  var initializeBeforeAfter = function($item) {
    // Only do this once!
    if (!$item.hasClass('already-done')) {
      // Initalize the beforeAfter plugin
      var $beforeafter = $item.find('.before-after');
      // Root of my problem; cannot refer to beforeAfter() function 
      // of 'beforeafter' module, loading sequence gets messed up?
      $beforeafter.beforeAfter({
        showFullLinks: false,
        imagePath: 'dist/images/before-after/'
      });

      resizeBeforeAfter($item);

      $beforeafter.mousemove(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $thishandle = $($this.find('.ui-draggable-handle'));
        var $thisfirst_wrapper = $($beforeafter.find(
          '> div:not(".ui-draggable-handle")')[0]);

        var mouseX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;

        $thishandle.stop().animate({'left': mouseX - 2}, 0, 'linear');
        $thisfirst_wrapper.stop().animate({'width': mouseX - 2}, 0, 'linear');
      });

      $item.addClass('already-done');
    }
  }

  return {
    initializeCarousel: initializeCarousel,
    resizeCarousel: resizeBeforeAfter
  };
});
```

I would appreciate any help, would also ask for advice regarding require() and define() usage in this project. Should I apply different calling structure? I've read a lot on the subject, but I can effectively learn only from live case examples :(

Comment: Looks like you are invoking beforeAfter function of var $beforeafter which is a JQ Element object rather than the module beforeafter.

Comment: I'm doing the same with owlCarousel: 
var carousel = $('#carousel');   
carousel.owlCarousel(options);  
and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've managed to solve the problem by forcing requireJS to load questionable modules before anything else. I've changed **config.js** part

```
// Start the application
require(['main']);
```

with

```
// Start the application, but make sure everything is loaded
require(['beforeafter', 'owlcarousel'], function() {
  require(['main']);
});
```

I will wait till Monday for a better solution, if anyone is willing to show a smoother approach and short explanation as to why this inconsistency is happening.

Comment: i has same problem and solve with this solution. i think it not good solution do you have any idea ?